# Import sql file in node.js and execute against PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm looking for an efficient way to take a raw sql file and have it executed synchronously against a postgres database, akin to if you ran it through `psql`.

I have an sql file which creates all databases, imports data, etc. I need to execute this using node.js but cannot find any module which does this automatically. For the node.js application itself, we use node-postgres ('pg'), knex.js and bookshelf.js. I assume though that pg is best for this.

One alternative I can think of is to read the full file, split it by semicolons, replace newlines with spaces, trim any duplicate space, then feed it into pg one by one in a manner that they're executed sequentially, not asynchronously. I'm a little surprised if this is truly the most efficient way and also if no libraries exist yet to solve this. I'm a little hesitant to jump into it seeing as SQL syntax can itself be a little challenging and I might accidentally mash it up.

Some clarifications in advance:

- `psql` cannot be used as it's not installed on the target machine
- I've chosen to develop and source control sql statements in sql native form, because it's a lot easier for a DBA to use and manipulate it

Comment: It's harder than your first thought because you need to distinguish literals from keywords within the SQL. As a trivial example, _split by semicolons_ can't work with `insert into table values(';');`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've written the following function which works *for my* case. It would have been much more simpler if it weren't for:

- Using `batch` to manage concurrency
- Having the tricky PostgreSQL COPY case to consider

Code snippet:

```
function processSQLFile(fileName) {

  // Extract SQL queries from files. Assumes no ';' in the fileNames
  var queries = fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ") // remove newlines
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ') // excess white space
    .split(";") // split into all statements
    .map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
    .filter(function(el) {return el.length != 0}); // remove any empty ones

  // Execute each SQL query sequentially
  queries.forEach(function(query) {
    batch.push(function(done) {
      if (query.indexOf("COPY") === 0) { // COPY - needs special treatment
        var regexp = /COPY\ (.*)\ FROM\ (.*)\ DELIMITERS/gmi;
        var matches = regexp.exec(query);
        var table = matches[1];
        var fileName = matches[2];
        var copyString = "COPY " + table + " FROM STDIN DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER";
        var stream = client.copyFrom(copyString);
        stream.on('close', function () {
          done();
        });
        var csvFile = __dirname + '/' + fileName;
        var str = fs.readFileSync(csvFile);
        stream.write(str);
        stream.end();
      } else { // Other queries don't need special treatment
        client.query(query, function(result) {
          done();
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Beware that this would fail if you used semicolons anywhere except to terminate SQL statements.

Comment: Can you add details on what `batch` is?

Comment: What about importing scripts with functions?

Answer (score 49):

You can just separate consequent queries with a semicolon when passed to `client.query`

That works:

```
var pg = require('pg');

pg.connect('postgres://test:test@localhost/test', function(err, client, done){
        client.query('CREATE TABLE test (test VARCHAR(255)); INSERT INTO test VALUES(\'test\') ');
        done();
});
```

And consequently, that works too:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var fs = require('fs');

var sql = fs.readFileSync('init_database.sql').toString();

pg.connect('postgres://test:test@localhost/test', function(err, client, done){
    if(err){
        console.log('error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    client.query(sql, function(err, result){
        done();
        if(err){
            console.log('error: ', err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this initially but found problems:
* Newlines and tabs found traditionally in SQL files could not be stuffed into client.query, (resolvable with some extra steps)
* Very difficult error handling per-query (which I have admittedly also left out of my example here)

Comment: @rgareth I had completely no problems with newlines and tabs in SQL files whatsoever. You can add some `\n`s (even `\r\n`s) and `\t`s to my example and it will still work.

Comment: that worked for me for ibm_db lib. I was facing the same problem also, but one question raised up to my mind. What about SQL Injection?

Answer (score 4):

The [`@databases/pg`](https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/sql#-sqlfilefilename-) client supports running SQL files out of the box:

```
const createPool = require('@databases/pg');
const {sql} = require('@databases/pg');

const db = createPool();

db.query(sql.file('my-file.sql')).catch(ex => {
  console.error(ex);
  process.exitCode = 1;
}).then(() => db.dispose());
```

It also supports having multiple statements in a single call to `db.query`:

```
const createPool = require('@databases/pg');
const {sql} = require('@databases/pg');

const db = createPool();

db.query(sql`
  INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (${'Forbes'});
  SELECT * FROM users;
`)).then(
  results => console.log(results)
).catch(ex => {
  console.error(ex);
  process.exitCode = 1;
}).then(() => db.dispose());
```

In this example, each statement is run in sequence, and the result of the last statement is returned.

Comment: while your answer helped me, you could mention that `@databases` packages are created by you. :smiley: … Also the docs (at your website) could be improve to contain more examples, e.g. I (as a Node JS newbie) had trouble to get where to put the connection options, because all your examples use a single string in `createConnectionPool()`, however, I can put there an object with the supported connection options. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @tukusejssirs If you have suggestions for improvements to the docs, I'd love it if you could submit at PR. All the files you would need to edit are here: https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/atdatabases/tree/master/docs

Comment: You ought to edit your answer to mention you are the author of the packages you are recommending.

Answer (score 2):

The following, which just reads a file into a string and runs it using [`query`](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#clientquery---text-optional-values-promise) seems to work for me:

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const pool = new Pool({ host, port, user, password, database });
dbClient = await pool.connect();

var sql = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/file.sql", "utf8");
await dbClient.query(sql);
```

In case it also helps, here is further code to run all "*.sql" files in a directory in alphabetical order:

```
const pathWithSqlFiles = "/path/to/sqldir";
const filenames = fs
  .readdirSync(pathWithSqlFiles, { withFileTypes: true })
  .filter((item) => !item.isDirectory() && item.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".sql"))
  .map((item) => item.name);
for (const filename of filenames) {
  var sql = fs.readFileSync(`${pathWithSqlFiles}/${filename}`, "utf8");
  await dbClient.query(sql);
}
```

(Don't forget to close the client connection at some point after this using `await dbClient.end()`).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to import a database through SQL file the simplest and fasted way is to just run this command in you cmd where your file is saved:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d myDataBase -a -f myFile.sql
```

Or you can read and parse the file through node.js and run it. But it would take time.

```
function processSQLFile(fileName) {

  // Extract SQL queries from files. Assumes no ';' in the fileNames
  var queries = fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ") // remove newlines
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ') // excess white space
    .split(";") // split into all statements
    .map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
    .filter(function(el) {return el.length != 0}); // remove any empty ones

  // Execute each SQL query sequentially
  queries.forEach(function(query) {
    batch.push(function(done) {
      if (query.indexOf("COPY") === 0) { // COPY - needs special treatment
        var regexp = /COPY\ (.*)\ FROM\ (.*)\ DELIMITERS/gmi;
        var matches = regexp.exec(query);
        var table = matches[1];
        var fileName = matches[2];
        var copyString = "COPY " + table + " FROM STDIN DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER";
        var stream = client.copyFrom(copyString);
        stream.on('close', function () {
          done();
        });
        var csvFile = __dirname + '/' + fileName;
        var str = fs.readFileSync(csvFile);
        stream.write(str);
        stream.end();
      } else { // Other queries don't need special treatment
        client.query(query, function(result) {
          done();
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```